# how to insert duplicate index in list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, append

```
idx = []
for i in all_users:

   self.query(*i)
   if self.query(*i) == True:
       print("yes")
   else:
       print("No")
       rem = all_users.index(i)
       idx.append(rem)

print(list(idx))
```

so this works, but the problem is when there is a duplicate value in all_users and for which self.query is false, it inserts the first index of the value.

```
e.g, all_users = [[2,5,7,9,4], [17,18], [4], [17,18], [5]]
idx = [1,2,1]

idx = [1,2,3] #correct
```

so if i have an empty list in all_users, and i dont want to pass it to the query function, how do i append that in idx? #edited

Comment: What does `self.query(*i)` do? What are you *trying to accomplish*, it isn't clear from your code, and indeed, your code includes a lot of stuff that we have no idea. You need to provide reproducible examples if you want help. And ideally, a well-specified problem statement.

Comment: I suspect your problem comes from the use of `rem = all_users.index(i)`, which will *always give you the first matching index*. Instead, you shuold iterate over the index *and the element* using `enumerate` like so: `for i, e in  enumerate(all_users): do_stuff_with_index(i); do_stuff_with_element(e)`

Comment: it returns a boolean value, if it returns false, for a list in all_user, the index of the list should be inserted.

Comment: Right, so you should do what I said above. Also, `if self.query(*i) == True:` should be `if self.query(*i):`, and `print(list(idx))` has a redundant call to `list`, because `idx` is *already a list*, unless you meant to create and throw-away a copy for no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you `loop` in a `range` of `all_users` length so you keep track of `index`, like:

```
idx = []
for i in range(len(all_users)):

   self.query(*all_users[i])
   if self.query(*all_users[i]) == True:
       print("yes")
   else:
       print("No")
       idx.append(i)

print(list(idx))
```

Comment: You should really just use `enumerate`.

Comment: Also, this is tagged Python 3, so this will throw a `NameError`, since `xrange` will not be defined. You just need `range`, but again, you *really want enumerate*.

Comment: so if i have an empty list in all_users, and i dont want to pass it to the query function, how do i append that in idx?

Comment: I don't know what you query function does, but if you want to check if the `list` is empty you can use `if all_users[i]: #pass to func` `else: #append index to idx`